# How to use GTK+3 GtkImage in XML *.ui files from GtkBuilder

Tags: xml, gtk3, gnome, gobject, flatpak

I am looking for more info on how to include a [GtkImage](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImage.html) in an XML UI file, instead of creating them directly from code (In [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImage.html) it only shows an example to create a GtkImage from C code and I want to do it from a *.UI resource).

What are the best practices for making icons or empty states with GtkImage in *.UI XML syntax? EDIT: Especially also in context of Flatpak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is my research so far.

This depends on whether you want to add an **Icon** from the existing icon set or add **your own custom resource/image** to your application. For GTK+3 we use the same class. For GTK+4, there is talk about having separate classes for icon and image. Below is instructions for GTK+ 3.

NB: In this example I added the GtkImage and GtkLabel inside a [GtkBox container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654275/i-added-a-gtk-widget-to-the-main-window-ui-file-but-it-doesnt-show-up/57654363#57654363), as GtkWindow only allows one widget.

---

**Adding a pre-defined Icon**

See list of icons with the GTK+3 [Icon Library](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.design.IconLibrary).

Here is an example taken from [Polari's source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/polari/blob/master/data/resources/main-window.ui#L60) on how to create a GTK Icon.

```
<object class="GtkImage">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="icon-name">open-menu-symbolic</property>
  <property name="icon-size">1</property>
</object>
```

You can change the scale using either `icon-size` (4 is the default size we use for GTK+ applications) or `pixel-size` (should be a multiplier of 8, 16 or 24). Regardless of what you choose, both should work fine for Hi-DPI.

---

**Adding a custom icon or image (PNG, SVG, JPG, etc)**

This process requires two additional steps first, before we can write the XML code.
1. Put the image inside the src/ folder of your application source code.

2. Register `MyImage.png` into the `org.gnome.MyApplication.src.gresource.xml` gressource file you have in src/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/org/gnome/MyApplication">
    <file>window.ui</file>
    <file>MyImage.png</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

3.
Now we can add the `GtkImage` to our UI XML file.

```
<object class="GtkImage">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">False</property>
  <property name="resource">/org/gnome/MyApplication/MyImage.png</property>
  <property name="icon_size">1</property>
</object>
```

As can be seen, the path consists of the gresource `prefix` + the filename.
By default, the image will be rendered 1:1.
My own experiments have so far shown that you cannot use `pixel-size` or `icon-size` to control the size of a custom image file loaded like this.

[image: custom image loaded from XML]